# If the gate returns true, the view should display edit button. In contrast, it should only show the buy button. Laravel 8 Gate with @can

Tags: laravel

this is my blade view code :

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                    @can('checkIsAdmin')
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                    @endcan
```

this is my gate logic :

```
Gate::define('checkIsAdmin',function(){
            $i=0;
            if($i==0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
```

All I want is simple. if the gate is true, the @can should be true too. So The edit button is displayed. Else, only buy button is displayed.

Comment: checkout https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-blade-templates

Answer (score 3):

you should fix your code like this:

```
@can('checkIsAdmin')
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
@else
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
@endcan
```